# Dividing Troops between multiple bases

Tags: xenonauts

**How should I organize my troops between multiple bases?**

The game gives a broad overall strategic choice of **whether place all of your best troops and equipment in a single A Team, or to split your best resources over multiple teams across the world** at the cost of each having less experience and equipment (as well as a higher literal monetary cost).  Having a single powerful team makes missions in the area surrounding that base easier.  Meanwhile, having multiple teams provides the possibility of performing ground missions across multiple continents, but is very (perhaps even prohibitively) expensive and each team will be less survivable than they otherwise would be.

There is also the matter of **Base Defense.**  These missions are quite difficult, and you want to bring as much power as possible.  Is it more prudent to **defend one base with your A Team** and sacrifice / bank on the others not getting hit?  Or is it plausible to **defend 2 or 3 bases with all B Teams** without having any A Team (as well as do well in the rest of the game this way)?

**What is the most strategically sound way to divide my power between bases?**

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this would largely be a matter of personal preference, but I would not just rely on batteries/turrets at secondary bases as they rarely do the job: my strategy has been, whenever you recruit less-than-optimal troops at your main base, transfer them to a secondary base as its defense force. Keep a few Hunters with MG's at each secondary base, along with a few missile batteries/etc. to back them up. When not being sent out on a mission, equip all the soldiers with MG's or shotguns, plus gas grenades, and if your base does get attacked, have everyone hunker down in the command room.

- Have most of your guys pointed at the door into the command room, but don't forget to scan the corners every turn if wraiths are in action, as they will ruin your day.
- Enough MG's should be able to mow down any reapers coming in.
- Take cover behind the computer consoles and what-not and against the wall next to the door.
- If the aliens decide to wander around and waste your time, send out a Hunter to fire potshots at them and lure them in.
- If the door opens with groups of guys on the other side, use gas.
- Avoid using explosives in this situation if at all possible, as you want to keep your command room intact (it's typically the most easily defensible area).

Every once in a while (or if they're the only team within range), send your B-teams out to do a mission with assault rifles/etc. Gaining some stats will make them better at defending the base (especially when building reaction and TU's). When you update your A-team to better gear, give the B-teams the hand-me-downs.